# How to generate Laravel Link with anchor

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I use Laravel URL::Route for link pages, And I passed query string like following code, but how to add anchor tag for this?

> eg: myproject.local/projects?week_ending=value#anchor

How to do that #anchor part with URL::Route? thank you

```
URL::Route('projects', array('week_ending'=>$week_end_day))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious way for that will be:

```
URL::Route('projects', array('week_ending'=>$week_end_day)) . '#anchor'
```